# Google sheet script suddenly stops working and fails to send email attachment due to attachment authentication failure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth, gmail-api

**Software:** Google Sheets & Google App Script

Hi all,
I have been sending test emails to myself with attachments from my google sheet. They have been going great. Then I hop on one day and start receiving authentication errors. I have tried several different fixes but I'm still stuck. I'm not sure why it broke if I didn't change anything. Anyways, I'm changing stuff now to try and fix it.

It will let me send plain emails, but when I try to attach pdf's or xsls files, it fails. This was working great until it stopped working... Setting 'muteHttpExceptions' : true, allows the email to send, but the attachments are empty / corrupt.

Do you know of a better way to send specific sheets via email as pdf's or perhaps a way to fix this?

**Code:**

```
function SampleEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var sheetName = ss.getName();
  var email = "test@gmail.com";
  var subject = "Important Info!";
  var body = "Test email.";

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/export?" + "format=pdf" + "&gid=" + sheetgId + "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': false
  });

  var contents = result.getContent();

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, { attachments: [{ fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content: contents, mimeType: "application//pdf" }] });
}
```

---

**Error message:**

```
5:58:33 AM  Error   
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
 (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
SampleEmail @ code.gs:108
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting the pdf to Google Drive and then adding it as an attachment? this might be happening because of the URL.

Comment: I have not tried that. Using the method you suggest, would it send it as an attachment or a link?

Comment: It can be done both ways but if you want to attach the file you need to get the file as a blob using DriveApp.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will look into this approach and report the results here.

Comment: It appears to be working now. Here is what I think solved it: I tried what you said mostly: I created a function to send the google sheet tabs to a google drive folder. Then, I went back to the original email script and simply tried running it and it worked. Think that sending the files to the drive somehow reset the getOAuthToken() and allowed it to work again.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**    (Thank you @Amit_Singh for the advice.)

Try running this function to send your google sheet as a pdf to your google drive. This cleared the cache or something with the getOAuthToken() for me and allowed the original script to authenticate and send email attachments properly. Here is the function:

```
function convertSheetToPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var sheetId = sheetgId; // "2SqIXLiic6-gjI2KwQ6OIgb-erbl3xqzohRgE06bfj2c";
  var spreadsheetName = "My Spreadsheet";
  var destination = DriveApp.createFolder('new folder');
  //var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vFL98cgKdMHLNLSc542pUt4FMRTthUvL");
  //var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + sheetId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/export?" + "format=pdf" + "&gid=" + sheetgId + "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  blob.setName(spreadsheetName + ".xlsx");
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```